# Solr deletes/optimizes affecting ranking score

Tags: search, lucene, solr, ranking

anyone know why Solr's ranking is affected by deleting (but not purging) documents?

ie. if I add a document and search for it, its score might be 4.7 but then if I re-add it (ie Solr deletes the old and adds it again... with same values) then do the same query the result has a score of 4.5. If I do an optimize on the indexes then the score again returns to 4.7.

I reckon this is due to the difference between maxDoc and numDoc in Solr when a document has been logically deleted, but not purged from the index.

Is this a bug? In my case it is causing problems as the sort order ends up unstable when an unrelated document (not in my result set) is deleted.

This is Solr 3.2.0

-Matt

Comment: I wouldn't worry about absolute values changing... the real problem is that *relative* values seem to be changing, thus affecting ordering...

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a bug, rather how Solr works by default - as you surmise deleting a document doesn't actually remove it until you optimize, thus the statistics still reflect the deleted document until that point. The benefit is that it makes deletion a fast operation (optimisation is usually done as an occasional process). Some other engines (such as Xapian) do actually delete documents completely.

Comment: I understand how/why it doesn't actually deleted the doc, but why is it using maxDoc for the idf calculation? Everywhere I read online seems to suggest that is uses numDoc:

http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/DefaultSimilarity.html#idf(int,+int)

Yet, when I do a query and get it to explain it gives me:

<str name="LC059C4D2">
12.179339 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(CPLNumber:LC059C4D2 in 143251), product of: 1.0 = tf(termFreq(CPLNumber:LC059C4D2)=1) 12.179339 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=143270) 1.0 = fieldNorm(field=CPLNumber, doc=143251)
</str>